# Accelerating downwards faster than gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-body-diagram

What would happen if you were in an elevator that was falling downwards with ***a*** acceleration and ***a***>***g***? I found an answer on this site that said that you'd hit the ceiling of the elevator. I understood that. But then wouldn't the elevator ceiling exert a downward force on you? How much would that force be?

Comment: $m(a-g)$ will be the normal force exerted by the elevator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would hit the ceiling of the elevator, as you are in freefall state, where the elevator is accelerating downward with acceleration more than 'g'. Thus you will hit the ceiling and now the ceiling will apply a downward force on you ,
$$F=m×(a-g)$$
[Where m is your mass]
Thus happens because your body is experiencing a force of $mg$ due to gravity, but the ceiling is forcing you to move with the elevator experiencing a force $ma$.
Thus, net force applied by elevator ceiling is $ma-mg=m×(a-g)$.